# In Java, while returning the thread to the pool, is the garbage collection automatic?

Tags: java

In Java, I am creating new heavy objects from a thread in a thread pool. How to garbage collect those created objects while returning the thread to the pool? Is it automatically garbage collected?

I am trying to understand how thread pools work in Java.

Comment: Garbage collection is anlways automatic. Nothing to do with any specific event.

Comment: When you say automatic, do you mean immediately?

Comment: Thanks for your responses! how long it takes to garbage collect after there are no references to the object?

will the garbage collection removes objects from old gen space as well ?

Comment: You need to make your objects eligible for garbage collection by not holding any references to them.

Comment: Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 1):

You commented:

> how long it takes to garbage collect after there are no references to the object?

Answer is: "it depends". Different [garbage collectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) have different policies and behaviors. Furthermore, the changing situation at runtime may impact those policies and behaviors.

So there is no deterministic way to predict when the memory taken by an object will be reclaimed.

> will the garbage collection removes objects from old gen space as well ?

The rule is simple: Any object no longer referenced becomes a candidate for eventual garbage collection. (There may be special cases such as [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), but you can generally ignore those.)

Keep in mind that different versions, and different implementations, of Java come with various garbage collectors. Not every garbage collector is [generational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Generational_GC_(ephemeral_GC)). And particular generational garbage collectors will vary in their policies and behaviors.

So, as said above, there is no deterministic way to predict when the memory taken by an object will be reclaimed.

Generally you need not worry about garbage collection. Trying to out-think the garbage collector is usually a case of *premature optimization*, and may well produce counterproductive results.

If you believe you have a special case, and need help in selecting a particular garbage collector implementation, you should post a question describing those specific details along with an outline of your concerns.

You asked:

> how to garbage collect those created objects while returning the thread to the pool?

First of all, you should generally be using the Executors framework in Java 5+ to manage your threads, not manually handling your own threads and pools.

Secondly, threads have no direct impact on garbage collection. When an object no longer has any reference pointing to it, from any thread, then it becomes a candidate for garbage collection. Eventually either (a) a garbage collector will reclaim the object’s memory, or (b) the app ends and all memory is returned to the OS.

If you use any [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) objects in your platform threads, then you have a responsibility for clearing those before ending your use of a pooled threads. By definition, any `ThreadLocal` object “sticks” to its thread. So a thread returned to a pool, retains its `ThreadLocal` object references. When that thread gets assigned to a new task, the thread brings along its pre-existing `ThreadLocal` objects.

In contrast to platform threads, [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) (Java 21+) benefit from being so “cheap” with RAM & CPU as to have no need for pooling. Like a [facial tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_tissue), each time you need a virtual thread, take a fresh new one, use, and dispose. This eliminates the concern over pre-existing dirty `ThreadLocal` objects.

You asked:

> is it automatically garbage collected?

Any object no longer referenced becomes a candidate for eventual garbage collection.

Comment: _"threads have no direct impact on garbage collection"_ minor quibble: threads are GC roots. Objects referenced on the stack of a thread are not eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified: the garbage collector remove all object not even referenced by anything 'live', so if your big-one is not reference at all, it will be collected asap according GC policy.